# why can sync.me app customize the incoming call screen?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have always been told that `"incoming call"` screen is not `customizable`, because of apple's controls. But this app has obviously modified the incoming call screen.

link here: [Check this](http://techcrunch.com/2012/11/15/sync-me-closes-4m-in-funding-to-scale-up-its-social-contact-syncing-ios-app/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20Techcrunch%20%28TechCrunch%29)

Just wonder how this is done, because this app is on app store, meaning we don't need to root iOS.

Can any one help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the way the article is worded, it sounds like the sync.me app scans your friends social network status updates and appends them to the picture you have saved on their contact info.

The call screen is not being modified. Just the picture associated with the contact.

Comment: yeah, but if you look at this, [link](http://img01.36krcnd.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/SmartSync.jpg), there is a small view showing you the contact's current status. Though in itunes, it seems sync.me removed the small view. Might be a false alarm ;[

Comment: That small view is a embedded in the contact pic @MJN is taking about.